# To convert .iso file to .img file while trying to dual boot with linux

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

[image]

It says no such file or directory.where did I go wrong?

Comment: In the past; I'm pretty sure all that I needed to do was change the filename extension, via `mv`, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path, by the looks of it, ought to be
`~/Downloads/` or `~/Desktop/` rather than
`~/Users/Yourname/…`

`~/` is already the shortcut to `/Users/Yourname/`

You can also use the `file` command to check that the file you are converting already exists. Copy the path and paste it after `file` at the shell. You can also shorten the directories, by changing to the folder

```
cd ~/Downloads
mv file ~/Desktop
cd ~/Desktop
ls ubuntu*iso
hdiutil convert -o ubuntu.img -format UDRW ubuntu*iso
```

The ls command makes sure there is only one file starting with ubuntu and ending in iso on your desktop - you can put the whole file path instead of using the * that I used for brevity if you have more ISO files that match on the desktop.

Comment: I have to disagree with "`~/` is already the shortcut to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Yourname/`" since in this reference `~` is actually the value of `$HOME` which under OS X is typically e.g. `/Users/username` not `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/username`.

Comment: semantics… it still arrives at that point, `bootdrive/users/me/`